# Javascript function does not execute when called

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have the following code:

```
function firstQuote(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=mycallback",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "jsonp",
  }); 

  function mycallback(json){
    document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = json[0].content;
  }
};
window.onload = firstQuote;
```

It is a simple function, but it is not being executed. If I take the code outside of the function it works perfectly. I'm stuck at it for some time now. Please, could someone help me?

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare Wrong.

Comment: Yes, this is not the answer

Comment: @CaioCésarSilvaGomes can you clarify the "it is not being executed" bit. Did you try keeping breakpoints using the developer console/console.log something within the function to verify?

Comment: @connexo I was assuming the OP wanted the callback to be within so as to use JS closures or something :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to define the callback inside the `firstQuote` function. (If you look at the error console, you'll see "[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: mycallback".) Separate those functions to put `mycallback` on the global scope:

```js
function mycallback(json) {
  document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = json[0].content;
}

function firstQuote() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=mycallback",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "jsonp",
  });
};
window.onload = firstQuote;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="quote"></div>
```

Comment: I get your point Daniel. Is there a way of getting the jsonp object and inserting it on the div quote with the same function? In this case firstQuote.

Comment: And what is the normal way? I'm new to ajax and json.

Comment: Hm....now that I try it, that particular server refuses the request unless you include that _jsonp param. So I guess in this case that is the way to do it.   (Sorry, I'm more used to non-JSONP ajax, where you'd normally use the returned Promise, chaining a `.then()` or `.success()` or etc after the call.)